# Interfacing Arduino with Python Serial

Tags: serial, arduino-due

I am implementing an FIR filter using Arduino. I am using an input signal as an audio signal. The audio signal has a duration of 3 seconds with total samples, 66150. What I am doing is reading this file in python and storing the data in an array. Using Serial, I want to send this sampled data to Arduino serial and process it, then send it back to serial and receive in  Python.

**Python Code**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.fftpack import fft
from scipy.io import wavfile # get the api
import serial, time

samplerate, data = wavfile.read("sample.wav")
samples = len(data)
plt.plot(data[:20000])
arduino = serial.Serial('COM4', 9600, timeout=.1)
time.sleep(1) #give the connection a second to settle

for i in range(0,samples):

    arduino.write(data[i])
    time.sleep(1)
    print(arduino.readline())
```

**Arduino Code**

```
  void setup() {

  Serial.begin(9600);
  }
  int i = 0;
  int newdata[10];
  void loop() {
     if(Serial.available() > 0) {
          int data = Serial.read();
          newdata[i] = data;
          Serial.print(newdata[i]);
          i = i+1;
        }
   }
```

The problem I am facing is that I am stuck at very first step. As a check, I sent 10 samples values at start from Python to arduino using a loop and tried to recover them back to read on Python console. These values were not correct. When I entered a string inside the arduino.write(), it was receiving but when I input a variable inside the arduino.write(), it doesn't print that value after transferring back to python. 
I just tried many things like changing to string but I didn't get the desired result. The output for this code is attached. Tomorrow is my submission and I am stuck in this thing. Help will be highly appreciated.[image: Python cmd window output]

Comment: I want just to check whether the value I am writing to arduino from python is correct or not. Firstly I sent string from Python to arduino it was fine. But when i tried variable data, it doesn't catch that value. The very first step is going wrong  so I can not proceed further (for processing stage).

Comment: int values or float values which are stored in data array are not being transferred to arduino. So if I can't get proper value of x[n] at a point it will not be useful for implementation of an FIR filter.

Comment: I just edited the question with more explanation. Kindly look over it.

Comment: first problem. you don't reset i

Comment: second problem. you read a byte/character and then print it as int. but print(int) will output the number as text. use `Serial.write(data);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a way to tackle this.
Here is my arduino code:

```
char buf[100];
const double coefficients[28] = {
-0.006416610121367, -0.01179616274682, -0.01212859343535,-0.001491136183145,
 0.0175211951058,  0.03193599126761,   0.0259553014052,-0.004580133449276,
-0.04206485416456, -0.05260424218688,-0.007566809377484,  0.09242896920118,
 0.2100842841173,   0.2894365184419,   0.2894365184419,   0.2100842841173,
 0.09242896920118,-0.007566809377484, -0.05260424218688, -0.04206485416456,
-0.004580133449276,   0.0259553014052,  0.03193599126761,   0.0175211951058,
-0.001491136183145, -0.01212859343535, -0.01179616274682,-0.006416610121367
};

int order_of_filter = 27;
int sample_array[28] = {};
double output_sample = 0;
void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.setTimeout(50000);
}
void loop()
{
  int  sample_in;
  int num_read = Serial.readBytesUntil('\n', buf, 100);
  buf[num_read] = '\0';
  sscanf(buf, "%d", &sample_in);
  for (int i = order_of_filter; i > 0; i--)
  {
    sample_array[i] = sample_array[i-1];
  }

  sample_array[0] = sample_in;

  for(int i = 0; i<=order_of_filter; i++)
  {
    output_sample = output_sample + sample_array[i]*coefficients[i];
  }
  Serial.println(output_sample);
  output_sample = 0;
}
```

And here is my Python Code:

```
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  from scipy.fftpack import fft
  from scipy.io import wavfile # get the api
  import serial, time
  import numpy as np
  import sounddevice as sd

  arduino = serial.Serial('COM4', 9600, timeout=1) #COM port depends on the USB port
 time.sleep(3) #time to get connection ready
 # %%

 fs, data = wavfile.read('hfsound.wav')
 samples = len(data)
 #Plot the signal
 plt.plot(data[:samples])
 plt.ylabel("Amplitude")
 plt.xlabel("Time") 
 plt.title("Time Domain Response of the Input Signal")
 plt.grid()
 plt.show()
 #Plotting fft
 fft_input = fft(data)
 half_length = int(len(fft_input)/2)
 omega_axis = np.linspace(0, fs/2, half_length)
 fft_n = fft_input[:half_length]
 plt.plot(omega_axis,abs(fft_n))
 plt.xlabel('frequency')
 plt.ylabel('Amplitude')
 plt.title("Frequency Domain Response of the Input Signal")
 plt.grid()
 plt.show()
 # %%

 #Declare an Array of zeros
 outputArray = np.zeros(64000)
 #Sending data to aurdino
 for i in range(samples):
     number = data[i]
     string = str(number).encode(encoding='utf-8') + b'\n'
     arduino.write(string)
     byt = arduino.read_until();
     print(byt.strip())
     outputArray[i] = byt.strip()

 arduino.close()
 # %%

 #Plotting Output waveform
 #Plot the time-domain output signal
 plt.plot(outputArray[:len(outputArray)])
 plt.ylabel("Amplitude")
 plt.xlabel("Time") 
 plt.title("Time Domain Response of the Output Signal")
 plt.grid()
 plt.show()

 #Plotting fft of output
 fft_out = fft(outputArray)
 half_length = int(len(fft_out)/2)
 omega_axis = np.linspace(0, fs/2, half_length)
 fft_n = fft_out[:half_length]
 plt.plot(omega_axis,abs(fft_n))
 plt.xlabel('frequency')
 plt.ylabel('Amplitude')
 plt.title("Frequency Domain Response of the Output Signal")
 plt.grid()
 plt.show()
 # %%

 #Playback code
 sd.play(outputArray, fs)
 # %%
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    arduino.write(data[i].tobytes())
    time.sleep(.1)
    print(int.from_bytes(arduino.readline(),byteorder='little') )
```

Is this what you whant?